# How to remove the e-mail to which the registration notification comes?

Tags: civievent, civimail, registration

Can you help me please!
How to remove the e-mail to which the registration notification comes? When someone is sign upped, im getting an email, that "A new user with the username "randomname" has registered...

Thanks!

Comment: Generally a notice about a 'new user' would be coming from the CMS not the CRM. Check if one of those contacts that you are being notified about also has a CMS user account and if they do then you may want to reframe your question

Comment: Thanks, yes, she have an account, where can i turn off registration notices for a cms account?

Comment: Which CMS are you using?  The question is tagged as 'civievent' - do you mean they are signing up for an event, or that they are signing up as a user on your site?

Comment: In a CiviEvent it will be using a Profile. In the Profile is an Adv. Setting which can say 'create a CMS user'. This could be what is creating the account, but it will be your CMS that sends out the mailing. CiviCRM is not the right channel to ask how to disable that. But if you do not want the user created then the Profile is the place to first look.

Comment: Thank you so much!